# 'toolText' as a label for FushionChart's Trendline

Tags: javascript, attributes, tooltip, fusioncharts, trendline

I need to display a label over the trendline in Fushion Chart(Column2D) like the image attached. Please let me know if it is possible. If it is not, please suggest a relevant solution with the static label.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with the [`annotation`](http://www.fusioncharts.com/dev/advanced-chart-configurations/annotations/introduction.html) feature.